# How to resolve the "Failed to resolve component: Button" error in Nuxt 3 unit tests using Vitest?

Tags: unit-testing, nuxtjs3, vitest

I am encountering this error while running unit tests for my Nuxt 3 application using Vitest. The error message indicates that the "Button" component cannot be resolved. The component is registered and used in my application, but it seems to be missing in the unit tests.

Here is the relevant code in my test file:

```
import { describe, expect, it, afterEach } from "vitest";
import { mount, VueWrapper } from "@vue/test-utils";
import Register from "../Register.vue";

describe("Register", () => {
  let wrapper: VueWrapper<any>;
  function createWrapper() {
    wrapper = mount(Register);
  }
  afterEach(() => {
    wrapper.unmount();
  });
  it("should render two inputs", () => {
    createWrapper();
    expect(wrapper.findAll("input")).toHaveLength(2);
  });
});
```

I have tried registering the "Button" component in my test file using Vue.component and importing it using import. However, the error persists.

How can I resolve this error and make sure that the "Button" component is available in my Nuxt 3 unit tests?